# ZF2 - How do I get application config items within my model?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my job I am dealing with a legacy app running on ZF2.  There is a model which is sending out a variety of different emails to difference addresses.  The one thing they have in common is they all need to BCC to one particular address.

At first,  in my head I was cursing the previous developer, for foolishly hard coding the email address 20 different times in one file.  I assumed that it would be a piece of cake to grab an application config with a simple call **$this->config->get('x')** (like in Laravel) or something along them lines. Now I find myself feeling bad, because I understand why the previous dev did hard code the email addresses.

So to the question,  how the hell do I grab a config item from application.config.php inside the model?  I keep reading about how I need to implement the ServiceLocaterAware Interface.  Is this really necessary?  There must be a way to grab configs easily, surely?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How the hell do I grab a config item from `application.config.php` inside the model?

You shouldn't do so *inside*, do it '*outside*'.

Register your model class as a service in `module.config.php`.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Email\Model\EmailModel' => 'Email\Model\EmailModelFactory',
    ]
],
```

Then create the factory `Email\Model\EmailModelFactory`, this uses the service manager to fetch the 'email' config key and injects it into the model's constructor.

```
namespace Email\Model;

use Email\Model\EmailModel;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class EmailModelFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new EmailModel($this->getEmailOptions($serviceLocator));
    }

    // Return the email options
    public function getEmailOptions(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $options = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        return $options['email'];
    }
}
```

The issue you will now have is all calls to your model classes will have to use `$serviceManager->get('Email\Model\EmailModel')` (rather than `new \Email\Model\EmailModel`) in order for the configuration to be injected. Even without seeing any of your legacy application my guess is that this would be difficult.

The model should not be responsible for sending emails; you could replace it with an service class, e.g. 'EmailService' and repeat the injection example above just for this class.

```
EmailService::send(EmailModel $email, array $options);
```

This would keep your model independent and there would be no need to replace the calls to `new Model` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It seems a lengthy process to do something that should be simple.  I am not into all the hand holding Laravel does, but something like pulling in global configs should be easy.

Comment: This is a *service locator*, hell it even has service locator in it's name. That's an **anti-pattern** that directly opposes Dependency Injection. It makes a liar of your object API. This is not the way forward in *any* object oriented language, never mind PHP.

Comment: @Jimbo Please explain to me the specifically the part above that makes you think this? By simply stating the use of a service locator over a DI container is 'anti-pattern' is just plain wrong and doesn't add any value. My guess it that you have read about service locators being misused; perhaps coupling them with the service that is being created? If so I would recommend reading the basics on ZF2, specifically [service factories](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html#writing-a-factory-class) as this really isn't the case in the above code.

Answer (score -1):

You need the service locator / service manager

Within your controller:

```
public function xxxAction()
{
    $sm      = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $config  = $sm->get('config');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access it within the model.  It seems wrong to pass through the email into each method  call inside the controllers?

$emailModel->sendStaffReply($query, $customer->email, $parent, $config->bbcEmail);